# How can I check the type of an Array in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a function with the following signature

```
public async sequenceAnimations(animations: AnimationPlayer[] | AnimationTracker[]): Promise<any>
```

In the function itself I want to branch based on if it is an AnimationPlayer array or an AnimationTracker array so I tried this:

```
let mappedAnimations = animations;
if (animations instanceof Array<AnimationTracker>) {
    mappedAnimations = animations.map(anim => anim.animationPlayer)
}
```

As you can see I am trying to allow the caller to pass either an AnimationPlayer array or an AnimationTracker array which has an instance of animationPlayer. But I get an error when checking instanceof the Array with a type

> The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.

Also the autocomplete isn't registering the type of the array in the if-block so I assume I can't check the array type like this.

What is the proper way to determine what the type of array being passed is?

Comment: Can you create a wrapper class AnimationPlayerList and AnimationTrackerList and test against these classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `instanceof` with a generic type with type parameters. After compilation all generics are erased so `animations instanceof Array<AnimationTracker>` would turn into `animations instanceof Array` which would not do what you expect it to do.

Since in Javscript arrays are not typed there is no build-in way of differentiate between `AnimationPlayer[]` and `AnimationTracker[]` and if the arrays are empty, at runtime they are really indistinguishable. You can however create a custom type guard that uses the first non-null item in the array to determine the type. For empty arrays this would always return `false` but it might be an ok solutions in most cases:

```
function isArrayOf<T>(array:any[], cls: new (...args: any[]) => T) : array is T[] {
    for(let item of array) {
        if(item != null) return  item instanceof cls;
    }
    return  false;
}
async function sequenceAnimations(animations: AnimationPlayer[] | AnimationTracker[]): Promise<any> {
    let mappedAnimations = animations;
    if (isArrayOf(animations, AnimationTracker)) {
        // animations is AnimationTracker[]
        mappedAnimations = animations.map(anim => anim.animationPlayer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **You can't**.

The main idea of TypeScript is to add types at **compile time** and emit plain JavaScript code after compilation. JavaScript itself has no support for advanced type checking and thus you're only option is to do duck-typing at runtime.