# How do I assert a generic array's type at compile time?

Tags: function, typescript, generics, type-safety

```
function concat<T extends string | Buffer>(input: T[]): T | null {
    let input0 = input[0];

    switch (typeof input0) {
        case "undefined":
            return null;

        case "string":
            return input.join("");
    }

    return Buffer.concat(input);
}
```

AFAIK the above switch cases (similar to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48708533/2175501)) would do the job *at runtime*, but my IDE complains about the last two return statements.

E.g. `input instanceof Buffer[]` doesn't work as well.

Comment: Where is `Buffer` defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the type of an Array in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708298/how-can-i-check-the-type-of-an-array-in-typescript)

Comment: No, that's **not a duplicate**. I've read that question and already applied the accepted answer "a custom type guard that uses the first non-null item" in my code. But there was still a problem – resolved by the accepted answer *here*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a simplified example of string or number arrays. As an aside, there is a slight difference between `(string | number)[]` and `string[] | number[]` - the latter is an array of elements of the same type, the former is an array that might contain both. I have included both examples as they suit different use cases (please note I'm anticipating what other people might be doing when they find your question in the future).

I have simplified the example as I can only guess at the `Buffer` implementation, and because the simple version suffers the exact same problem as your original code.

## Recursive Handling on Individual Elements

This one handles mixed arrays, i.e. where each element may be a string or a number.

This example takes the input array and sorts it into strings and numbers by checking each item in turn.

```
const strings: string[] =[];
const numbers: number[] = [];

function example(input: (string | number)[]) {
    const [first, ...others] = input;

    if (typeof first === 'string') {
        strings.push(first);
    } else {
        numbers.push(first);
    }

    example(others);
}
```

## Check and Assert

This one handles arrays that contain a single type, either all strings, or all numbers.

In this example we use a type assertion to tell the compiler that if the first item is a string, they are all strings.

```
function example(input: string[] | number[]) {
    const first = input[0];

    if (typeof first === 'string') {
        return (<string[]>input).join('');
    } else {
        return (<number[]>input).map((n) => n.toString()).join('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn. Yet another elephant oversight of mine. `(T1 | T2)[]` vs. `T1[] | T2[]` Thank you!